# How to merge two files in linux and only keep rows from one file?

Tags: linux

I have two txt files in Linux.

fileone.txt has 40 rows. col names are: A B C D

filetwo.txt has 50,000 rows. col names are: D E F G

I would like to merge the two files (using column D) but only keeping the 40 rows from fileone.txt

So I'd like filethree.txt to have 40 rows and col names: A B C D E F G

What command do I need to do this?

Comment: Possibly `join(1)`. See `man join`.

Comment: Well join(1) man page says that the files must be sorted on the join field, also I do not see a way to exclude the rows that were not in fileone.txt. I think this problem may be an example of why PERL and then ruby and python were invented. For myself I would just write a small python script.